# Get A team project and create a work item without using get the work items store

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem, team-project

I am Using the code below to create a new work item under a certain project programmatically using c# as below:

```
        TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
        TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetFullyQualifiedUriForName("http://tfssssrv:8080/tfs"));


        //Get data store that contains all workitems on a particular server
        WorkItemStore store = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

        //Get particular Team Project
        Project project = store.Projects["MAKAROV"];
```

I am being able to connect but the **tfs.GetService()** to get the stores is taking a lot of time to get the Data (around 148 Team Project and 70000 work items). I need to retrieve the Team Project without going through the Store and create the work item under it. i am sure there is another way but can't seem to find it on the internet.

Comment: Why do you have so many team projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to manipulate work items in TFS 2005 through 2013 without getting the WorkItemStore object. In 2012 & 2013 the speed has been greatly increased but if you have lots of Team Projects you can still have performance issues.

The recommendation is to cache the object.